# ng-autocomplete options values are not bind with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

Im using [ngAutocomplete](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete) directive for autocomplete the city field. The issue I'm facing now is its not binding the selected option from drop down into ng-model. Only first letter of the city or what ever letters I typed is bind with the ng-model not values from drop down is binding with ng-model.  Eg. If typed ''c'' some city will shown in the drop down starting with ''c''. I can select one option, then the input field will be updated but ng-model value is bind as ''c''.

Anyone please help me.

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are pressing enter after typing the letters trying selecting from the drop down first and then press enter or submit using submit button. 
If above is the case with you, you can disable enter functionality or enable enter after selecting from the dropdown.

Comment: not pressed enter key just using mouse or touch pad for selecting the option and clicking the submit button.